# Laravel Cashier - determining default payment method without bloat

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I would like to loop through all the payment methods and determine which is the default.

Getting all can be done using `$_paymentMethods = $user->paymentMethods();`

But there is no key showing which is default. Not sure if I'm missing something. I have to do something like:

```
$paymentMethods = [];

        foreach($_paymentMethods as $_paymentMethod) {
            $method = [
                'id' => $_paymentMethod->id,
                'card' => [
                    'last4' => $_paymentMethod->card->last4,
                    'exp_year' => $_paymentMethod->card->exp_year,
                    'exp_month' => $_paymentMethod->card->exp_month,
                    'brand' => $_paymentMethod->card->brand
                ]
            ];

            if ($user->hasDefaultPaymentMethod()) {
                $method['default'] = ( $_paymentMethod->id == $user->defaultPaymentMethod()->id );
                
            }

            array_push($paymentMethods, $method);
        }
        
        // default at the top
        usort ($paymentMethods, function ($left, $right) {
            return $right['default'] - $left['default'];
        });

        // to object
        $paymentMethods = json_decode(json_encode($paymentMethods), FALSE);
```

This causes considerable page load time. is there a better way to determine which is the default?

Comment: Yes, this is too heavy loading, anyone can answer this?

Comment: A bit late but, ```$user->defaultPaymentMethod()->id``` this shouldn't be inside the loop. You're performing an API request I believe on each iteration.